# show count author post today

Tags: users, author

i want show user count post today or yesterday post in wordpress.
example:

xxxx = published 2 Posts
yyyy = published 40 Posts

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Basic logic behind what you want:

1. Find out the actual date e.g. $date_now
2. Get posts by author http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts_by_author_sql that have the same publish date as $date_now (you need to do a sql query for that).
3. count the rows that were returned and echo the output.

Comment: I can't write sql code

Comment: i found this code 
<?php
function countUserPosts($userID) {
 $userposts = get_posts('author=4'); 
 return count($userposts);
}

// USAGE
echo 'Author has published'.countUserPosts('4').' Posts';
?>... this code total count author post. how show count author post today?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this at the moment but I believe that `WP_Query` with the new, as of 3.7, `date_query` will do this.

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'yesterday', 
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'author' => 1,
  'fields' => 'ids'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts_by_author = $query->found_posts;
```

Again, I can't test this right now and I haven't used `date_query` much at all. I am guessing... a lot. I think that might get you moving though.

Comment: thank you but
I using this code but does not work.

Comment: I am sure I have something wrong then, but I am away from my devs server. I will see what I can do later, unless someone spots the problem.

Comment: Try replacing `yesterday` with a date like "January 1st, 2013" (form the Codex). The docs imply that a string acceptable by `strtotime` should work, and "yesterday" is such a string, but that is my first guess as to where the problem is.

Comment: yes.. i found this code <?php
function countUserPosts($userID) {
 $userposts = get_posts('author=4'); 
 return count($userposts);
}

// USAGE
echo 'Author has published'.countUserPosts('4').' Posts';
?>... this code total count author post. how show count author post today?